# SerialPort to send command and to get response

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm creating a program to work with some equipment using serial port. I have documentation where there're details how to send command by port. It works very well but I should get some information about status of the equipment. I tried everything but I'm not confident in these type of developing. May be I missed something.

**From the documentation:**

There are totally 21 commands, 20 commands are of opening, 1 command is of reading status

Open command:

Address Command fixed value（ 0x55） lock number

Address 0XF2 0X55 0X01

Address 0XF2 0X55 0X02

Address 0XF2 0X55 0X03

......

Above commands execution

Success returns :
Address+0X59+0X59

Failure returns: Address+0X5E+0X5E

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Send open lokcer door command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="boardAddress">0 means open left slave cabinet，1 means open right slave cabinet</param>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] OpenBox(byte boardAddress, byte command)
    {
        var openCommand = new byte[5];
        openCommand[0] = (byte)(255 - boardAddress);
        openCommand[0] = 0xF2;
        openCommand[1] = 0x55;
        openCommand[2] = command;

        openCommand[3] = 0X00;
        openCommand[4] = 0X00;
        try
        {
            if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                //serialPort.WriteBufferSize = 5;
                serialPort.Open();
            }
            serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            serialPort.Write(openCommand, 0, 3);
            return openCommand;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Locker cell can not be opened.", ex);
        }
    }
```

It works very well but last 2 bytes return nothing. They are always 0X00. Also I'm using SerialPortDataReceived but I always get 0 there.

```
 public void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DBException.WriteLog("");
        DBException.WriteLog("Serial port data received");
        var sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        DBException.WriteLog("Read existing = " + sp.ReadExisting());
        try
        {
            DBException.WriteLog("Length = " + sp.BytesToRead);
            if (serialPort.BytesToRead == 4)
            {
                var readBuffer = new byte[4];
                sp.Read(readBuffer, 0, serialPort.BytesToRead);

                DBException.WriteLog("Read serial port :" + readBuffer.ByteArrayToString());

                //                    RaiseLockerStatusEvent(readBuffer.ByteArrayToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DBException.WriteLog(ex);
        }
    }
```

**QUESTION 1** How to get Success or Failure returns? I think they should be in the last 2 bytes.

**QUESTION 2**
How to get all states? I get nothing at the present.

**Documentation:**

Read lock status command: Address + Data1 + Data2 + Data3
Address: 0XF10X55
Data1 Data2 Data3
0000 lock20 … lock17 lock16 … lock9 lock8 … lock1
The first 4 digits is fixed number of 0000
Sample:
0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0001 means lock1 and lock9 is open, others are closed
Note: for some type of electronic lock, “1” means close, “0” means open.

My snippet

```
/// <summary>
    /// Send check machine(cabinet) status command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="address">0 means check left cabinet, 1 means check right cabinet </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] SendCheckLockControlStatueCommand(byte address)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            var checkCommand = new byte[6];
            checkCommand[0] = Convert.ToByte(255 - address);
            checkCommand[1] = 0xF1;
            checkCommand[2] = 0x55;

            checkCommand[3] = 0x00;
            checkCommand[4] = 0x00;
            checkCommand[5] = 0x00;
            try
            {
                if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    //                    serialPort.WriteBufferSize = 5;
                    serialPort.Open();
                }

                //Send inquiry command
                serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                //                    serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                serialPort.Write(checkCommand, 0, 6);

                return checkCommand;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Locker cell can not be opened.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever use the asynchronous `DataReceived` event the way you do! You need to decide: Either you want to communicate synchronously or asynchronously. If you want the latter, never call or even *wait* in `DataReceived`.

Instead, put the stuff you receive into a buffer and handle it as soon as a message is complete.

Also, the call to `ReadExisting` already reads everything from the serial port that is there so that `Read` is highly probably to block!

It should rather look something like this:

```
List<byte> receivedBinaryData = new List<byte>();

public void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string availableData = sp.ReadExisting();
    byte[] inputAsASCII = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(availableData);

    DBException.WriteLog("");
    DBException.WriteLog("Serial port data received");
    DBException.WriteLog("Read existing = " + availableData);
    try
    {
        // Add the bytes to the receivedBinaryData List
        receivedBinaryData.AddRange(inputAsASCII);

        // If the message length is reached or exceeded, do something
        if (receivedBinaryData.Length >= 4)
           ....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DBException.WriteLog(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I'm getting into it. But actually I prefer to communicate synchronously. And I think I should Wait for some time in my SendingCommand method and then Read data. Could you explain it please? I'll be appreciate.

Comment: I think I have found the right answer to read data from serial port. It'm gonna use AutoResetEvent all details are here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782053/serialport-wait-for-response Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to communicate synchronously, you might want to call `Read` after you `Write` until you have your answer. Please note that this might block your application forever if there is no answer. Using a WaitHandle with a timeout may indeed be the best solution.